# Lenovo X1 Yoga 3rd Gen Issues After Suspend

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, suspend, 18.10

After a suspend event my TrackPad/Mousepad, trackpoint and the keyboard stop working.

Otherwise Ubuntu runs great.

I am running Ubuntu 18.10, but the problem persists from 18.04. In fact I was hoping that with 18.10 the problem would go away...

I believe it has something to do with the S3 sleep but I would appreciate to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of issues with touchpad after suspend. I solved it by installing bios version 1.27:

1. Download from Lenovo https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds502368)
2. Use this method to flash the ISO to a bootable USB: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/SUPPORT-REQUEST-X220-BIOS-UPDATE-INSTRUCTIONS-USB/m-p/553427#M3283 (I had to find the script elsewhere)
3. Reboot, and apply. Note that there are lots of scary messages when updating bios, but it worked for me.

Now I can suspend, and open lid up, and keep working, without any touchpad problems.